# Play a sound, wait for it to finish and then do something?

Tags: c#, multithreading, audio, synchronization

I'm writing a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application which is supposed to play three sound files and at the end of each sound file, it's to change the source of an image.

I can get it to play the sounds using `System.Media.SoundPlayer`. However, it seems to play the sound in a different thread, continuing on.

The net effect of this is that only the last sound is played and all the images are changed.

I've tried `Thread.Sleep`, but it sleeps the whole GUI and after the sleep period everything happens at once and the last sound it played.

**UPDATE**

I thought PlaySynch was working, but it seems to freeze my GUI which is less than ideal. What else can I do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Did you try [SoundPlayer.PlaySync Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.playsync.aspx)? From the help:

> The PlaySync method uses the current
>   thread to play a .wav file, preventing
>   the thread from handling other
>   messages until the load is complete.

Comment: Yeah I just found this, the only problem is that the Gui doesn't seem to be drawn... Will keep on working on it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Play method, use the [PlaySync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.playsync.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
[DllImport("WinMM.dll")]
public static extern bool  PlaySound(byte[]wfname, int fuSound);

//  flag values for SoundFlags argument on PlaySound
public static int SND_SYNC        = 0x0000;      // Play synchronously (default).
public static int SND_ASYNC       = 0x0001;      // Play asynchronously.
public static int SND_NODEFAULT   = 0x0002;      // Silence (!default) if sound not found.
public static int SND_MEMORY      = 0x0004;      // PszSound points to a memory file.
public static int SND_LOOP        = 0x0008;      // Loop the sound until next sndPlaySound.
public static int SND_NOSTOP      = 0x0010;      // Don't stop any currently playing sound.
public static int SND_NOWAIT      = 0x00002000;  // Don't wait if the driver is busy.
public static int SND_ALIAS       = 0x00010000;  // Name is a registry alias.
public static int SND_ALIAS_ID    = 0x00110000;  // Alias is a predefined ID.
public static int SND_FILENAME    = 0x00020000;  // Name is file name.
public static int SND_RESOURCE    = 0x00040004;  // Name is resource name or atom.
public static int SND_PURGE       = 0x0040;      // Purge non-static events for task.
public static int SND_APPLICATION = 0x0080;      // Look for application-specific association.
private Thread t; // used for pausing
private string bname;
private int soundFlags;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------
public void Play(string wfname, int SoundFlags)
{
    byte[] bname = new Byte[256];    //Max path length
    bname = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(wfname);
            this.bname = bname;
            this.soundFlags = SoundFlags;
            t = new Thread(play);
            t.Start();
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------

private void play()
{
    PlaySound(bname, soundFlags)
}

public void StopPlay()
{
    t.Stop();
}

public void Pause()
{
    t.Suspend(); // Yeah, I know it's obsolete, but it works.
}

public void Resume()
{
    t.Resume(); // Yeah, I know it's obsolete, but it works.
}
```

Comment: I think that is seriously overkill.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is do an async sound, but then disable your UI in such a way that it doesn't respond to user response. Then once the sound is played, you re-enable your UI. This would allow you to still paint the UI as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. I used PlaySynch, but I did the playing in a separate thread to the code the draws the UI. The same thread also updates the UI after each file is played.