# Thread.Sleep is not working as expected in Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, sleep

I have an application that uses a timer to 1 in 1 minute perform refresh data in a DataGridView. Depending on the information to return the screen, a different sound will play. Each sound has a playback time. I am using this command to have the effect of duration of my music.

```
Thread.sleep(GetMusicDuration[i] * 1000);
```

When I start my application the first time, everything goes well, but when the timer runs TICK event that carries the information in the DataGridView again and run PLAY to play the sounds my Thread.Sleep command does not work, it simply ignores not expect the time set for parameter.

```
public void PlaySound()
    {
        try
        {
            while (1 == 1)
            {
                List<string> distinctMusic = GetMusicFile.Distinct().ToList();
                StopSound();
                if (distinctMusic.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < distinctMusic.Count; i++)
                    {
                        player.SoundLocation = distinctMusic[i];
                        player.Play();
                        Thread.Sleep(GetMusicDuration[i] * 1000);
                        StopSound();
                    }
                }

                DisposePlayer();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (generateLog)
                log.LogTxt(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Until now I did not understand why the exucução wrong.

someone could help me?

thank you...!

Comment: What are you trying to do? I guarrantee Thread.Sleep is the wrong approach **Edit** I just reread the question and perhaps try using a timer

Comment: I'm playing a song with the SoundPlayer class, and I'm running Thread.Sleep as playing time and then run the SoundPlayer.Stop ();

Comment: Are you sure you want to dispose of your player *inside* your while loop?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, because everything will be rebuilt again.

Comment: What value is in your `GetMusicDuration[i]`? If it's time in milliseconds, then you may be double-multiplying by 1000. For example, if `GetMusicDuration[i]` returns `60000` (60 seconds), then multiplying that against `1000` would yield 60,000,000 milliseconds (or 60,000 seconds). So perhaps your loop never iterates (or it would after 16.67 hours). Can you double-check that value? It _should_ be time in _seconds_.

Comment: Also, if this is the case, I strongly recommend switching to using `TimeSpan` instead. I suggest doing that _anyway_ even if it isn't the root cause; there's no point to manually managing milliseconds like that.

Comment: DataGridView implies it's WinForms. Sleep() kills the messaging loop, you're on the wrong path.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play a sound, wait for it to finish and then do something?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148676/play-a-sound-wait-for-it-to-finish-and-then-do-something)

Answer (score 0):

Thread.Sleep blocks the UI thread. You should use a timer in stead:

```
//Create a new timer that ticks every xms
var t = new System.Timers.Timer (GetMusicDuration[i] * 1000);

//When a tick is elapsed
t.Elapsed+=(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) => 
{
   //what ever you want to do
};
//Start the timer
t.Start();
```